# diseño de estilo CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

alguien puede ayudarme con el diseño de lo que coloco en l imagen siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código html, en el cual estoy trabajando:

```
<div Class="Contenedor">
<div Class="Cuadro">
  <div Class="Titulo">
   
    <h2> <img src="dinosaur.jpg" />HORA DESTACADA</h2>
  </div>
  <div Class="Info">
    <div Class="Fecha">
      <p>Hora Local</p>
      <div Class="Dias">
      <div Class="inicio">
        <spam> MAR </spam>
        <spam> SEP </spam>
        <spam> 18 </spam>
      </div>
      <div Class="fin">
        <spam> MAR </spam>
        <spam> SEP </spam>
        <spam> 20 </spam>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div Class="Poke">
    <img src="shiny.png" />
    <img src="poke.jpg" />
  </div>
    <div Class="Texto">
    <p> Aqui colocamos info</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el CSS en el cual requiero de su ayuda para poder lograr lo indicado, espero me puedan apoyar:

```
    h1 {
    font-family: Impact, sans-      serif;
     color: #CE5937;
    }
   .Cuadro{
   background: blue;

     }
   .Titulo{
     background: red;
    width:100%;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
        }
     .Info{
      background: blue;
     display: flex;

       }
      .inicio{
    background: black;
    color:#800080;
      display: flex;
      }
  .fin{
    background: black;
      color:#800080;
      display: flex;
      }
 .Poke{
     background: black;
      }
```

Me gustaría hacerlo tal cual la imagen y responsiva ( cuando esté en pc mostrar 2 cuadros y en celular mostrar solo un cuadro)

Espero su apoyo compañeros

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Recuerda además que, ya que es HTML + CSS, puedes mostrar un [repro] ejecutable a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`).